# Is there is anyway to manipulate HTML document from external domain inside the iFrame?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, cors, embed

I want to make some changes to the HTML document inside the iFrame which is coming from another domain, as an example, the document inside the iframe open links to `target="_blank"` and I want to change that target to another value before it's renders to the client's browser.

I always hit `CORS Cross-origin resource sharing`, I know this is against security purposes but my application is just a prototype for concept proofing.

I also tried to make it programmatically from the code behind the HTML by storing html content to a variable then pushing the contents after changing to a temporary HTML page, but have the same problem rather than faulty page that require some resources on the external source.

Does anyone know a solution or an out of the box idea that can overcome this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do it just with a browser, no; as you mentioned, it runs afoul of the Same Origin Policy. (Well, you could with a browser extension, but I'm assuming you're talking about something that would run in a normal environment without additional installation.)

You could do it by involving a server: Have your iframe use a URL on your server, and have the server fulfill requests for that URL by querying the third-party server for it and then relaying the result.

But not without something in-between like that.